# How to give class sibling elements by arrow's keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for move this class to sibling by keypress arrow's like 38, 40.
But, I am not sure how to figure it out. Here is it code:

This is just simple html table code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover 
ConfigPatternTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>PatNum</th>
      <th>varCode_M</th>
      <th>varCode_E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

And this is My javascript so far when you click on `td`, it will find closest `tr` and add class on it with background.

```
$(document).on('click','.ConfigPatternTable tr',function(){
    $(".ConfigPatternTable").find("tbody > tr").removeClass("selectedtr");
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass("selectedtr");   
});
```

Also This javascript is i am trying to figure it out

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  $(".ConfigPatternTable").keydown(function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
      console.log("testing also this")
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
      console.log("jsut testing this")
    }
  });
});
```

> And this is my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny6kzs8j/)

And with this code snippet hope I reach question requirements

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  $(".ConfigPatternTable").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
      console.log("testing also this")
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
      console.log("jsut testing this")
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('click','.ConfigPatternTable tr',function(){
 $(".ConfigPatternTable").find("tbody > tr").removeClass("selectedtr");
 $(this).closest('tr').addClass("selectedtr"); 
});
```

```css
.selectedtr > td{
 background-color:rgba(131, 78, 77, 0.4) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ConfigPatternTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>PatNum</th>
      <th>varCode_M</th>
      <th>varCode_E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Үйлдлийн хандлага</td>
      <td>Tends to Act</td>
      <td>Шаргуу</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e){
        var slcttr = $(".selectedtr");
          if(e.keyCode == 38) { 
             $( ".selectedtr" ).prev().addClass( "selectedtr" );
             slcttr.removeClass("selectedtr");
          } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 40){
              $( ".selectedtr" ).next().addClass( "selectedtr" );
             slcttr.removeClass("selectedtr");
          }
});
```

**I coded solution thank you upvoted**